# Finding streaks in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document in elasticsearch that has a property `won` that is of type boolean and a timestamp. I would like to see if there is a winning streak of eg 5.

So is there a sequence of at least 5 where won is true, without won being false in that duration, based on the timestamp.

I don't really have an idea on how to get started with this one. Checking if somebody won 5 times in the last 7 days should be possible with the date histogram aggregation, but that doesn't work for a streak kind of thing.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I just implemented streak logic using the date histogram aggregation (as you mentioned).